# NodeJS require script with different behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module, require

I'm writing a serverless application which contains a file, for simplicity let's call it `icecream.js`. Now I have multiple build and deployment methods.
**One** simply takes this file, `icecream.js`, and moves it into lots of other code needed for the purpose of that build. Let's call the script which was built, containing the same code (at some point) as `icecream.js`, `hotfudgesundae.js` [(Ice burried by delicious hot fudge)](https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/product/hot-fudge-sundae.html). I can't control the hot fudge that makes up the rest of the built script. I also can't control the build process.
Build process number **two** executes a script (Let's call it `sundaepie.js`) which needs the `module.exports` value of `icecream.js` ([We all know there must be some ice cream buried in there somewhere](https://www.bk.com/menu-item/hersheys-sundae-pie)). It **mustn't** execute any of the code `hotfudgesundae.js` needs when requiring it.
Now there's a fourth script, `SearchingSolutions.js`, which require's the `hotfudgesundae.js` script.
The only thing I can control is `sundaepie.js` and `icecream.js`, so I can change the way that sundaepie requires icecream.js and what icecream.js includes.
**PROBLEM:**  I need to write `icecream.js` in a way that the code it contains *IS* executed for `hotfudgesundae.js`, but not executed when required with `sundaepie.js`. The `module.exports` can stay the same.
**What I tried:** I can't just check if `module.parent` exists, because while `hotfudgesundae.js` doesn't require the script (`icecream.js` is baked into it when built), `hotfudgesundae.js` itself is required by `SearchingSolutions.js`.
I tried to make `module.exports` a function with one parameter, and if this parameter is given, return something, else execute the code that `hotfudgebrownie.js` needs. I would then call it like so `require('icecream.js')(true)` from `sundaepie.js` and require `hotfudgesundae.js` in the regular fashion from `SearchingSolutions.js` (since I can't control it), but it wouldn't execute the function when required without passing the brackets to invoke the function.

```
module.exports = function(isexport) {
    if (isexport) {
        return "For sundaepie";
    } else {
        console.log("Executing code in hotfudgesundae.js");
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work? If you have any questions go leave a comment ;)

Comment: Oh, you are just building up a future headache :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a *global variable* (yes, that hurts):

```
  // inside the module
  if(global.isCold) /*...*/

 // before you require it
 global.isCold = true
```

Comment: Thanks :) Sometimes I tend to be thinking in a  **scope** ;)